# White space underneath text - not padding or margin

Tags: css

I have a h2 element with the following properties;

```
border-bottom: 5px dotted #7298c2;
border-top: 5px dotted #7298c2;
padding: 15px 0;
margin: 15px 0;
line-height: 1; /* this was added after a suggestion that it could fix the issue /*
```

The problem is, there's a lot of white space underneath the text before it even gets to the padding. I can fix it by changing the padding to offset this but I would've thought there'd be an easier way of fixing this.

Please see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: If you add a lower letter e.g. _"g"_, you'll see why...and this is font related as well, so the offset will be unique for each family. Also, add a [mcve] as with an image dump we can't test it.

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be in the font. Does this also happen with other fonts?

Comment: Yes, it seems to fit perfectly with a lower case 'g'. I guess the solution is to modify the bottom padding to get it about right.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line height to 0.75 or 75%

```
line-height: 1;
```